# LinkedIn Lead Gen webhook into Pardot with Google Analytics parameters

Tags: linkedin-api, zapier, pardot

I have a webhook from my Lead Gen forms in LinkedIn to Pardot via Zapier but I can't get the Google Analytics UTM parameters to feed into my Pardot prospect information. Has anyone had success?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using webhooks try using a Pardot Form Handler.  [Using Pardot Forms or Form Handlers you can capture UTM parameters](https://forcery.com/pardot-utm-parameters-how-to/).

Zapier doesn't always play nice with dynamic variables, so if you're deadset on using webhooks, make sure the data is actually posting to Zapier.